# How to obtain a value from the user and store the objects into an array

Tags: java

I have created a class called Employee and i have set the variable for it. Now im creating an object for that class. In this object i want to create a function called "GetValue" and it should initialize the variables i have created in the class Employee. I want it to get e.g employee name, employe number etc. I have start some coding but im stuck on this..

```
//main class
public class Employee {

    //variable declaration

        private String EName, EDesig; 
        private double BSal=0.0, HA=0.0, GSal=0.0;
        private int EmpNo;


    // constructor;
     public void Employee (String EnNameParameter, String EDesigParameter, double BSalParameter, double HAParameter, double GSalParameter, int EmpNoParameter)
    {
        this.EName = EnNameParameter;
        this.EDesig = EDesigParameter;
        this.BSal = BSalParameter;
        this.HA = HAParameter;
        this.GSal = GSalParameter;
        this.EmpNo = EmpNoParameter;

    } // End constructor;

     // Get methods;
     public String getEName(){
            return this.EName;
        }
     public String getEDesig(){
            return this.EDesig;
        }
     public double getBSal(){
            return this.BSal;
        }
     public double getHA(){
            return this.HA;
        }
     public double getGSal(){
            return this.GSal;
        }
     public int getEmpNo(){
            return this.EmpNo;
        }


     //Set methods;
     public void setEName(String Ename){
         this.EName = EName;
     }
     public void setEDesig(String EDesig){
         this.EDesig = EDesig;
     }
     public void setBSal(double BSal){
         this.BSal = 0.0;
     }
     public void setHA(double HA){
         this.HA = 0.0;
     }
     public void setGSal(double GSal){
         this.GSal = 0.0;
     }
     public void setEmpNo(int EmpNo){
         this.EmpNo = EmpNo;
     }
}

import java.util.Scanner; 
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create object


        Employee a = new Employee();
        Employee b = new Employee();
        Employee c = new Employee();


        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter The Number of Employee");
        int number = input.nextInt();          

        int[] N = new int[3];                  // instanitate array
        int i;

        for(i=0; i<number; i++){

        }

        getValues();
        CalculateSalary();
        DisplayValues();


        }
}
```

Comment: In my main method i want to create N number of Employee objects, where the value of N is obtained from the user and store the objects into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
// make an empty list
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

// make a scanner that reads from stdin
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("How much employees does your company have?");
int n = sc.nextInt() // nr of employees

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // loop over all employees
    // read the information of the ith employee
    System.out.print("What is the name of the i th employee?");
    String name = sc.next();
    int age = sc.nextInt() 

    // make an employee object
    Employee employee = new Employee(name, age);
    employees.add(employee); // add the employee to the list
}
// Now you have a list with n employees

// to print all employees on stdout
for(Employee e : employees) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());  
    // make a toString() method in you Employee class, 
    // else this will not work properly
}
```

Comment: I hope you understand it better now, let me know if you don't understand specific parts.Try to run this code by putting it in the `main` method.

Comment: Im making an array simpler to this.... im not sure where im going learn..                                 BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   System.out.println("Enter number of employees: "); 
   int num = Integer.parseInt(bufferRead.readLine());
     
   int[] N = new int[3];//instantiate the array
   int i;
   
   for(i=0; i<num; i++){//repeat for as long as there are more employees
  
    getValues();
    CalculateSalary();
    DisplayValues();
     
   }
  }
  catch(Exception x){
   x.printStackTrace();

Comment: So the array should be in my main class Employee not in class test

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with all the employees. Imho, a scanner is much easier in use then a buffered reader.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an object array to the number input by the user. The following code will help you:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter The Number of Employee");
        int number = input.nextInt();          


        Employee[] emp = new Employee[number];  // create object array for no of employees
        for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
            emp[i].setBSal(100);
            emp[i].setEDesig(null);
            emp[i].setEName("Ann");
            emp[i].setEmpNo(234);
            emp[i].setGSal(34);
        }

        getValues();
        CalculateSalary();
        DisplayValues();
        }
```

This is the main class. You can either use user inputs to set each method.

Comment: that's the problem i know how to set it manually.. but im having trouble inserting the user inputs... how would i go about it...

Comment: use the scanner object to get each value from the user and pass it to the setter method

Comment: What do u mean main class.. I should have this in public class employee and not in public class test....

Comment: Why did u use SetBsal, when im using a scanner object.. cause im getting a message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: I was trying to get the code for you. But the same question got into me too. I'll look into it further.

Comment: Employee[] emp = new Employee[3];    // Creating an object array for number of employees
     
     for(int i=0; i<number; i++)
     {
      System.out.print( "Name of employee " +(i+1)+ ": " );
          EName = input.nextLine();
        }

Comment: It'll be true if the number of employee is 3 every time. Is it so?

Comment: ^^^^ that worked for me.... but Employee 1 and Employee 2 are in the same... and Employee 3 is in the next line... How can make Employee 1 and Employee 2 not in the same line.. i think i mess up ("Name of employee"+(i+1)+":");

Comment: But the problem is if user input a number more than 3 this will throw an array out of bound exception.